# Deleting user specified strings from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, list, text

I am writing a code that requires me to ask the user to input a name. If there is a match to that name in my text file it will delete that name from the text file. The text file is as follows:
-first name
-last name
-phone number
and all 3 of these items must be deleted from the text file when the user inputs the first name of that person.

So this is my current code and it is giving me an error saying that

> ```
>      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
>   at Ex8PhoneDirectoryDelete.main(Ex8PhoneDirectoryDelete.java:62)"
> ```

I am currently just trying to make it work by only inputting the second name in the list.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    c = new Console();

    int match = 0;
    int count = 0;

    String[] FirstNames = new String [10];
    String[] LastNames = new String [10];
    String[] PhoneNumber = new String [10];

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("phone_directory.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        FirstNames[i] = input.readLine();
        LastNames[i] = input.readLine();
        PhoneNumber[i] = input.readLine();
    }

    c.print("Please enter a first name to delete from the phone directory: ");
    String nameEntered = c.readLine();

    for (int k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++) {
        if (nameEntered.equalsIgnoreCase(FirstNames[k])) {
            //c.print("Match Found!!!");
            //match = k;
            //c.println(match);
            count = count + 1;
        }            
     }   

     c.println(match);

     String[] FirstNames2 = new String[10-count];

     if (count != 0) {
        c.println("There is a match.");

        for (int j = 0; j < match; j++) {
            FirstNames2[j] = FirstNames[j];
            c.println(FirstNames2[j]);
        }

        for (int l = match + 1; l < 10; l++) {
            FirstNames2[l] = FirstNames[l];
            c.println(FirstNames2[l]);
        }
     } else {
        c.println("There is no match.");                   
     }

     input.close();
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to start learning how to use a debugger in your IDE.

Comment: Naming your variables starting with capital letter is not a good practice...Only names of classes should be written starting with capital letter.

Comment: Yeah its bad habit and something I will try to break, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Parse the file line for line, for example with a [Stringtokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Your code looks like one contact inludes 3 lines, so if you match your first name leave out the 3 lines for that contact.

-> Check your contacts as block and write it in a new file after on leaving out the ones you want to delete.

Comment: What if I changed the text file so that all 3 sets of information were on one line apposed to 3 separate lines? Would that make it easier to code cause I would only have to skip one line then write the rest. Sorry for the lack of knowledge, I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: It's probably a little bit easier to handle, just make sure you use a char as separator that you don't use in your names and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why you're getting an *out of bounds* exception?

Looks likely that you could be trying to reference an area outside the constraint of `10`, possibly with the following line (particularly, the `match+1` part)

```
for (int l=match+1;l<10;l++)
```

Comment: If you're unsure about the question, write a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Still wet behind the ears - thank you for the advice.